npm fails install of any packages - TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm fails to install any packages, downloading any dependency related to eslint causes TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE error.
Here's what I tried:

clean npm caches - doesn't help!
npm audit verify , npm audit fix, npm audit fix --force
delete & reinstall npm (various attempts with various protocols for deletion and installation)
tried to disable eslint, but react app creation scripts contain it by default
tried to upgrade eslint version, but I get the same TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE when eslint is being installed

Here are the failed downloads from the logs after running npm install, npm init @eslint/config@latest or any other package install that has dependencies on eslint:
7097 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-deep-equal/-/fast-deep-equal-3.1.3.tgz 864ms (cache skip)
7098 warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
7099 silly tar Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/warn-mixin.js:21:40)
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/unpack.js:236:18)
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:83:14)
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.emit (node:events:530:35)
7099 silly tar     at [emit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:313:12)
7099 silly tar     at [maybeEnd] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:468:17)
7099 silly tar     at [consumeChunk] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:476:21)
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:427:25)
7099 silly tar     at Unpack.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:548:14)
7099 silly tar     at Pipe.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass/dist/commonjs/index.js:116:23) {
7099 silly tar   recoverable: false,
7099 silly tar   cwd: '/Users/gevorg.sargsyan/Projects/dev/js/fireship-memento/node_modules/fast-deep-equal',
7099 silly tar   code: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE',
7099 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE'
7099 silly tar }

7146 silly packumentCache corgi:https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fwebpack cache-miss
7147 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fwebpack 68ms (cache hit)
7148 silly packumentCache corgi:https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fwebpack set size:85201 disposed:false
7149 warn deprecated workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
7150 warn deprecated workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
7151 warn deprecated workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
7152 warn deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported. Please see https://eslint.org/version-support for other options.
7153 verbose stack Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/warn-mixin.js:21:40)
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.warn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/unpack.js:236:18)
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:83:14)
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.emit (node:events:530:35)
7153 verbose stack     at [emit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:313:12)
7153 verbose stack     at [maybeEnd] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:468:17)
7153 verbose stack     at [consumeChunk] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:476:21)
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:427:25)
7153 verbose stack     at Unpack.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:548:14)
7153 verbose stack     at Pipe.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass/dist/commonjs/index.js:116:23)
7154 error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
7155 error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
7156 silly unfinished npm timer reify 1730736384828
7157 silly unfinished npm timer reify:unpack 1730736388377
7158 silly unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/fast-deep-equal 1730736388382


Fixed using Claude.


Cleared npm cache completely:
rm -rf ~/.npm then
mkdir ~/.npm


Installed latest eslint globally:
npm install -g eslint@latest


